# Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.ResourceManager.ResourceGraph

Tags: c#, visual-studio, package, azure-resource-graph

Getting following error: Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.ResourceManager.ResourceGraph, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Have tried cleaning, removing and reinstalling the package, completely removing the .nuget folder, starting a new project and repulling the repo, eliminating all related code and references, various entries suggested on the InterWebz into the project file, but same error, over and over.

Something *slightly* suspicious: the package version on NuGet is 1.0.0 but the error references Version=1.0.0.0 (extra zero).

Note that the package works fine in a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved but in a flummoxing manner.  The solution is a project that makes a DLL and a demo project that uses that DLL to illustrate how to use the DLL in practice.  The Demo project does not call ResourceGraph at all, only the DLL does.  But when I added the ResourceGraph to the Demo project, the error went away.  That's not how it's supposed to work, right?  Or am I misunderstanding how dependencies work.  If a Project calls a DLL that has dependencies, does that Project also need to add the packages that the DLL uses?  I have not referenced the ResourceGraph package with "using" in the Demo program, but adding the package still fixed it. Thoughts?

Comment: You should be able to use [bindingRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element) to use the specified version.

Comment: If this method solves your problem, you can mark it as an answer. This can help someone with the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  It was not a version or bind redirect issue.  It was fixed by adding the package to the solution, but this feels more like a hack than a fix, so this issue's true solution remains elusive.